# TextView in iOS 8, Navigation bar is over Text View

Tags: swift, ios8, uiscrollview, textview, uinavigationbar

Hello I am using iOS 8 (swift)

Now I have this

https://www.dropbox.com/s/tu9issn0b61aphh/IMG_1304.PNG?dl=0

But I need this, so that the textview is showing the beginning of the text!

https://www.dropbox.com/s/0ggzndfr90vcrnj/IMG_1305.PNG?dl=0

I have try lots off stuff, but without success!

I need your help?

Comment: Are you using constraints?

Comment: Yes i use and autolayout

Comment: Could you please share a picture of of your constraints in storyboard?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/hs0hbvm06tcga2o/Ohne%20Titel.tiff?dl=0

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/qz8zdekno1von36/Ohne%20Titel%202.tiff?dl=0

Comment: Do you have any Solution ?

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't seem to reproduce the issue at my end. I'm running on 8.3
In my viewController I've set a property to false. Like 
automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
Screenshot is
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/21750763/iOS%20Simulator%20Screen%20Shot%2005-Jun-2015%2011.02.31%20pm.png

Comment: it is the same problem on 8.3. You have to give more text so that you can scroll!

Answer (score 2):

In your `UIViewController` implement the following function

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    myTextView.setContentOffset(CGPointZero, animated: false)
}
```

Also in `viewDidLoad` set the following property

```
automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
```

I'm unsure as to why this happens, but this will prevent it from happening.

Comment: thx it works, but it is hanging, is there a solution before view appear

Comment: If you set `animated: true`, it will have bit of a nice animation. If you do it anywhere before this time, I'm afraid it won't kick in.

Comment: This didn't work for me. Something still seems to be setting it back under the navigation bar.

Answer (score 1):

In the attributes inspector of your root view controller be sure that "Under Top Bars" is un-checked.